# Conformal mapping to the quarter disk

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Is it possible to **directly** find a conformal mapping between the right half-plane to the quarter unit disk in the first quadrant. I used the cross ratio formula
$$\frac{w-w_1}{w-w_3} \frac{w_2-w_3}{w_2-w_1} = \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_3} \frac{z_2-z_3}{z_2-z_1}$$
with the points $i, 0$, and $1$ respectively maps to $1, 0$, and $1$ to preserve orientation. Not sure whether that's the correct approach. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: $$z \longmapsto \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{e^{-i\pi/4}\sqrt{z}+2}}$$ works, I think. The idea is to map the right half-plane to the fourth quadrant (take square root then rotate counter-clockwise of $\pi/4$), inverse it wrt $-2$ (maps the fourth quadrant into the upper half of the circle with diameter $[-2,0]$), move the circle to the unit circle and take a square root again. I am not convinced you can do simpler: circles and lines are preserved by affine conformal maps and homographies turn lines into either lines or circles...

Comment: @Mindlack I'm looking at a similar practice problem where I have to map the open strip $$H = \{z \in \mathbb{C}| Re(z)<0, 0<Im(z)<1\}$$ onto the exact same quarter disk in the first quadrant. I know that $$e^{\frac{\pi}{2}z}$$ will map the open strip onto the half plane, and that the Möbius transfrom will map the half plane onto the unit disk, but I can't comprehend from your answer what turns the unit disk into the quarter disc

Comment: @MJP: because you have a condition on the real part, $e^{\pi/2 z}$ is exactly what you want. In my answer, I turn a half-circle into a quarter circle by taking a square root, but of course the wording is a bit misleading.